# Dexamethasone radius of gyration source

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

I am looking for a source for the radius of gyration of dexamethasone in aqueous solution. Does anyone know where I could get it from? Even better would be an estimation of the Stokes radius, but the radius of gyration will do.